# Mapping to or from elements of a set, when that set is an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is an embarrassingly stupid question, but a colleague and I disagree, and it is relevant to what we are trying to do. The question is, suppose you have a pair of sets $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{4, 5, 6\}$. Now if you have a set $C = \{A, B\}$, i.e., $C = \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4, 5, 6\}\}$, then the set $C$ definitely has two elements, and cannot meaningfully be thought of as having six elements...right? So if you have another set $D = \{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$, there is no surjective function from $C$ to $D$ because $C$ has two elements and $D$ has six, even though $C$ consists of elements that, as their own creatures, so to speak, contain three elements each?

I know this question is painfully dumb, so here's a question that's hopefully a little more interesting and clarifies why this is an issue: When you consider the set $C$, can a function, correspondence, or relation to or from $C$ ever meaningfully reference the elements contained inside $A$ and $B$? I have been saying no, but I am open to being told I am wrong about this.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. And trust me, this is by no means a dumb question. There are plenty of those around.

Comment: I'd like to be right, but maybe when you order the elements, you can say meaningful things about the elements in C? Judging by st. math's answer.

Comment: Eh, it depends on the specific sets being dealt with. In general, you can't really say much. Your position to me is more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no surjective map from $C$ to $D$ (if you do not include cases like $a=b=c=d=e\neq f$). Your reasoning is right.

But of course there is a function which can reference the elements inside the sets. It can, for example, choose the minimum of each set if you are in $\mathbb{N}$. Note the difference between the cardinality of a set and a function which points to elements of sets.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It sounds like I was wrong after all. Can you expand a bit on the last sentence? My reasoning, which is apparently wrong, has been that elements are basically just points, even if those elements are sets, and so you can't "dig into" the points with a function to extract "smaller" points. 

Let me give an example, without really knowing what a metric space is. Suppose C consists of A and B, and A and B both have 1 as the smallest element. Then it is meaningful to say that 1 is the minimum of C? Even though, in my maybe-wrong understanding, 1 is not an element of C?

Comment: Take $A=\{1,2\},B=\{A,\{2,3\}\}$ for example. Then you can define a function $f:B\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}, f(X)=\max(X)$. Then $f(A)=2\in A$ and $f(\{2,3\})=3$.

Or take the set $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and the power set $X:=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. Then, you can define a function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, where $f(A)=\min(A)$. This function takes the smallest element from each subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, so it has "access" to the elements in the set $A$.

In both cases, the function has "access" to what is in the set.

Comment: I'm so glad you answered this way. One more clarifying question: _can_ you actually do that? To me, when you take $f(A) = min(A)$, you are actually taking functions from many different individual sets, which can, _as a distinct matter_, be considered subsets of \N. I.e., are you _really_ accessing elements of the sets that are elements of $X$? Or is it just a convenient shortcut? Full disclosure: I am trying to understand why you don't need category theory to do such a mapping properly. Being precise about domain and codomain is important to me on this question. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Functions themselves are only sets (relations with special properties). In most cases, functions have an actual "functional meaning" (in real analysis; continuous functions; the $\max$ function from above; etc.). However, when looking at the definition of a function as a set of pairs of elements from domain and codomain, then each function is just doing what we defined it to be. So ultimately, it has access to elements of sets if those are in the domain, because we defined the function like that. Functions are just mapping elements to elements, and there doesn't need to be a real "connection".

Comment: I see what you mean. This has been very helpful. Thanks a lot!